# How to check if point has three or more lines snapped on to it in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point

I inherited a shapefile with lines and points. I need to make selection of all points that have three or more lines snapped at same point. The problem is that the network is pretty large and it is impossible for me to do it manualy.

Is there a way to accomplish this in ArcMap? To make selection of points with 3 or more lines that are conneted to it.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say a line is snapped to a point, do you mean that they share a vertex or point is intersecting the line? If it's just about the geometry intersection, use Spatial Join to count number of lines that intersect every point (you'll get a Count field to work with). If you need to make sure the line shares the vertex, explode your lines vertices to points and then use the Spatial Join to count how many points from line will intersect every source point.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.
I have pipeline network that consist from intersections as a point feature class and lines as a line feature class. They are all connected in a network.
Need to make selection in point feature class of all intersections that have 3 or more line that are connected to that intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box tool that would let you do the selection on your input point feature class. You will need to use the Spatial Join GP tool with the following parameters:

[image]

You will get created a new point feature class which will contain a new field `Join_Count` which will contain the number that represents how many lines a point intersects.

Here is a sample screenshot with the points and labels in read showing the value. You will need to use the `Select By Attributes` window then to select those which have a value larger than 3.

[image]

If you would like to automate this workflow, you might take a look at ModelBuilder or `arcpy` if you fancy learning some Python.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in doing this outside of ArcMap, you can accomplish this  with the [Networkx](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package in Python. First, export the polylines and points as shapefiles into some directory, then leverage Networkx like so:

```
import networkx as nx

#create graph, G, of your sewer network
G = nx.read_shp(r'path/to/shapefiles')

#list of nodes having 3 or more intersecting edges (i.e sewers)
nodes = [n for n, degree in G.degree_iter() if degree >= 3]

for n in nodes:
    #print out the object id of 3+ degree nodes
    print G.node[n]['OBJECTID']
```

The `[n for n, degree in G.degree_iter() if degree >= 3]` business is a Python list comprehension. Basically, this loops through each node (i.e intersection) in your sewer network and builds a list of nodes having 3 or more edges touching it.

Comment: networkx seems like a super powerful library. Is it like network analyst but just in pure python?

Comment: Yes, Networkx is similar to network analyst, but it's not dependent on ArcMap and can be used anywhere with pure Python. I started using it precisely because I couldn't deal with network analyst reliably and without losing my cool. There's is a bit of learning curve, but it's been worth it in my experience.